# Enable php on mac snow leopard

Tags: php, macos

Installed:

```
Entropy PHP 5.3.03.pkg
```

I have been trying to enable php on my mac. But everytime I point the browser to my test.php all I get is the source code being displayed:

I put my test.php in the following location:

```
user/admin/sites
```

And I browse to in using the following url:

```
http://localhost/~admin/test.php
```

and all I see is this:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I have done the following:

```
cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini

chmod 666 /etc/php.ini
```

I have enabled `web sharing` in `system preferences | web sharing`

I have also uncommented the line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I have restarted apache

```
apachectl restart
```

However, I always end up with the source code being displayed.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: First of all, Mac OS X comes with PHP preinstalled. You say you installed Entropy PHP, but I believe the steps you list above would be for enabling the Mac's built-in PHP, not for enabling Entropy. You may want to double-check Entropy's installation instructions.

Comment: @Mark. I didn't know that Mac comes with php preinstalled. So I have decided to remove it and go with the Mac Snow Leopard. However, I think I have mixed things up. I would like to start from a clean state. Is there any best way to start from a clean state and not using any bit of entropy's php? Thanks.

Comment: For a clean slate, you can re-install OS X, but I'm sure you don't want to do that. Giving you the right advice would take a closer examination of your current configuration. This really isn't a programming question. I think you should ask it on http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer your particular problem directly, but if you continue to have issues, may I suggest easy alternative? Install **MAMP**. Works like a charm with very little setup. Website here: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: I guess that is LAMP for Mac. Seems like a one stop solution. I will give that a try if I can't get my current problem solved. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to load php module on apache

in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf , uncomment following line

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and then restart apache

ref: http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard

Comment: Hello, I have done that already just edited my anwswer. thanks.

Comment: check error on /var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: I updated my question. However, it still fails to work. Thanks.

Comment: I have this warning: [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
And this error: [error] [client ::1] script '/Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: So I copied my test.php to /Library/WebServer/Documents/ however, I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: try to add test.php on /Library/WebServer/Document/test.php , apache localhost Document directory is /Library/WebServer/Document/ , if you want to use in your Home folder, you can do like $ ln -s /Library/WebServer/Document ~/WebServer

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up your apache root as users/admin/sites?  You need to do that too, so apache knows where to look.  Normally its somewhere like /var/www

Answer (score 1):

You need to add AddType to your server config:

```
AddType x-httpd-php .php
```

This can be done in .htaccess or httpd.conf file. The AddType directive maps the given filename extensions onto the specified content type.

Also check for

include /private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf in httpd.conf

Comment: Hello, Yes, I have added the AddType in the httpd.conf and also added the include line. Restarted apache and tried to browse to my test.php and got the same problem. If I browse to http://localhost/index.html I get the "Its Works". However, when I do this http://localhost/test.php I just get the php source code i.e. <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Thanks.