# php.ini.default cp php.ini config have some error in Mac OSX

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem about PHP configuration in Mac OSX.

The things is :

If I input the command :

```
cp php.ini.default php.ini
```

the php file can not be compiled.but the web server is working.

If I delete "**php.ihi**" and keep "**php.ini.default**" file .the php file can be complied.

And the **"extension_dir"** isn't work .

This is problem just like the question

[Enable php on mac snow leopard [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393714/enable-php-on-mac-snow-leopard)

But the following link have not resolve the question.

Any-guys can resolve it?

thank you very much .

Comment: What error(s) are you getting exactly?

Comment: in /etc/ directory. there is a "php.ini.default" file. if you change the name to "php.ini"   php will not work.

Comment: @adam Why doesn't it work? How doesn't it work? What does it tell you? PHP says `I don't want to work`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha .I have got the answer .

following the command :

```
vi /etc/php.ini
short_open_tag=off  ==> short_open_tag=on
sudo apachectl restart
```

now .everything is ok.